# Parse pointer to object EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have problem with parse. I have relation in my database between Event and Type. So, event has it's type, which consist of title and color(and other properties, but focus on relation)
Event:

```
@NSManaged var type: Type
```

Also, i have computer property eventColor:

```
var eventColor: UIColor{
return type?.typeColor ?? UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

And basic query:

```
override class func query() -> PFQuery? {
    //1
    let query = PFQuery(className: Event.parseClassName())
    //2
    query.includeKey("type")
    //3
    query.orderByDescending("startDate")
    return query
}
```

Controller:

```
var events = [Event](){
    didSet { eventsTableView.reloadData()  }
}
```

Im making request:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    if let objects = objects as? [Event] where error == nil{
        println("Count is: \(objects.count)")
        for event in objects{ 
            event.pinInBackground()
            println("\(event.type)") //Here, type is available... and it prints out
        }
        self.events = objects // Property observer is called
    }
    else{

        println("Handle error...")
    }
})
```

And code that is called after table view reload:

```
tableView cellForRow....(){
    let event = self.events[indexPath.row]
   let color = event.eventColor // BAD ACCESS, because "type"    dissappears.   
 }
```

So, after making this request, and assigning array of events to array in my view controller, i'm trying to read computer property event color and it fails(EXC_BAD_ACCESS). It seems like type object is available in block, which is executed after fetching events, but later it dissappears, and every time i want to read it, i have application runtime error.
I don't know, it feels like object is hold like weak in block(because i included "includeKey" and Type is downloaded), but later it's just immediatelly deallocated. What should i do, to prevent from deallocating type? I could make my own object of Type, not subclassing PFObject, but i believe that somewhere there should be the other, cleaner way.

Thank you

Edit:
Ok, so investigating a little bit more i discovered(cellForRow...)
I'm trying to get type and it's color property by subscripting PFObject:

```
let typeItem = eventItem["type"] as! PFObject
println("type is: \(typeItem)")
/*
type is: <Type: 0x7fe99bdf3330, objectId: dkEXw2r7zh, localId: (null)> {
    color = "#F29C31";
    name = swift;
}
*/
let colorFromType = typeItem["color"]
println("color: \(colorFromType)") //Works, returns valid value.
```

But writing it in other way:

```
let type = eventItem.type
let color = type?.color //Compiles, but runtime error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject color]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x7fe99bdf3330'
println("type: \(type), color: \(color)")
```

So i'm not entirely sure, why this happens. It looks like this type property of Event could not be casted to Type, but i'm sure that's type of property.

EDIT, RESOLVED:
Ok, i'm so stupid, i didn't know about register subclass, and Type.registerSubclass resolved all problems.

Comment: Are you saying the property in a block isnt available outside the block?  have you tried using a __bridge?

Comment: __bridge in swift is default behavior, and i think that's not the case. Essential is that i'm using Parse and it's objects. I think that this object "type" is available in closure, but later it's someway deallocated(ie. it's not hold by event in a strong relation)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to typecast the object in the `tableView cellForRow....()` call.

Your call to `.eventColor` will fail if it doesn't have the cast, and the cast isn't saved to your `self.events` as far as I can see. Try this:

```
tableView cellForRow....(){
   let event = self.events[indexPath.row] as! Event
   let color = event.eventColor 
}
```

Also, if you are using a subclass, you need to be sure to use `registerSubclass` ahead of time or your properties will not be available!

Comment: Hm, but self.events have the [Event] type already, and cast doesn't do anything. Or am i wrong? I suppose that it's rather problem with my misunderstanding of Parse behavior with fetching related objects.

Comment: Objects from Parse, as far as I know, are pinned at PFObject, not the subclass. I think you'll need to re-cast the events you pinned when you use them.

Comment: Hello, i edited my question by providing some more information about this casting issue. Casting works well with Event, but type property of Event could not be casted to Type.

Comment: Lol, just updated my answer and realized you figured it out - it was subclass registering! Glad it's working for you.

Comment: Ha, thank you very much for help :))) Really appreciate it.